# How to have a datagrid with filtering textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid

I would like to design a control like this:
[image]

Can someone advise me if I need to customize an existing control? Should I use datagrid? Or probably have a row of customized headers, then a row of filtering textbox, then a headerless datagrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if such filter can be added as field in Datagrid. The second option appears more likely.